# parameters of array to $facebook->api('/me/likes',

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post a video on my wall, I have tried using $facebook->api('/me/feed',post, array(...)) and works fine, but it only shows the "like" and "comment" functionality, I need to put the "share" functionality also.

I think I can work around it using '/me/likes' instead of '/me/feed' but I can't find anywhere which parameters should be inside the array

I am not really uploading a video, just the link to YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'me/feed' to post a video. Try setting the 'source' parameter.

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed','POST', array(
        'source' => 'http://www.youtube.com/asdf1234',
        'name' => 'My video on YouTube'
    )
);
```

See here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

> Source: A URL to a Flash movie or video file to be embedded within the
>   post